# How to append on the same line the variable

Tags: sed

I have test.txt file and I want to add my variable to specific line after the word. But my sed command not work how can I do this?

test.txt file is:

```
Hello:
Green:
Yellow:
```

My variable is

```
echo $variable

http://111.111.111.11
```

My bash command is:

```
sed '/Green:/r/dev/stdin' test.txt <<<"$variable"
```

My output after run the bash command:

```
Hello:
Green:
http://111.111.111.11
Yellow:
```

My desire output:

```
Hello:
Green:http://111.111.111.11
Yellow:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your variable directly into the substitution:

```
sed "s~\(Green:\)~\1$variable~" test.txt
```

This will match the string `Green:` and capture it into group `\1`, you can then append `$variable` to the captured group in the substitution. Note I have used `~` as a separator as your substitution string contains multiple slashes `/` which cause problems if you also use `/` as the separator.